# Determine continuity and differentiability of the real function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

I've been asked to analyze the domain, continuity and differentiability of the function $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^x}$$ I've already shown that this function is defined for every real greater than 1. Now, I suspect It is continuous and differentiable over It's whole domain, so I'm trying to use the Weierstrass M test to show that this series uniformly converges for every $x>1$. But all I have is  that if $x\geq2$ then $\frac{1}{n^x}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$, which combined with the fact $\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6<\infty$ results in that $f$ is continuous for $x\geq2$. But I don't know how to deal with numbers smaller than 2. 
I'd apreciate some hints or even better, some ideas to deal with these kind of problems in a more direct way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Travis Right, but how did Jose show the series converges for $x>1$ without knowing that?

Comment: The series *doesn't* uniformly converge on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: @Travis Am I using wrong the Weierstrass M test?

Comment: The series converges on compact subsets of $(1, \infty )$: this is enough to prove smoothness on every compact set. But this implies that it is smooth on its whole domain.

Comment: @JosePaternina No, there's only the one (well, in this context anyway). Crostul's argument is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Travis the fact that this series converges on compact subsets of $(1,\infty)$ is a consequence of applying the Cauchy's Condition for Uniform Convergence, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Riemann zeta function. Here are some useful things you can read: Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) !

Comment: Thanks, I already read the whole wikipedia's article a few hours ago in my attempt for understanding this series.